# Run iOS app as an background service

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have developed an app for iPad. I want to run it in the background. I know there is no straight way of doing this and I found the article [Coming Soon to Pastebot: Music in the Background](http://tapbots.com/blog/pastebot/pastebot-music-in-background) regarding this matter. But it is bit confusing and have no way of doing it. Is there anyone who has tried this? P.S This must not be a approach using any jailbreak and there is no need of worrying about that apple is not allowing this app to submit to their app store

Comment: [Here you are.](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/)